# Editor Template LabelFor - display value rather than name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, mvc-editor-templates

The below correctly renders a label and textbox for each item added to the list instantiated in the controller.

What I need is for the label to display the value of "FavouriteThingID" (i.e 1,2,3,4,5) rather than the literal "FavouriteThingID".

Any ideas?

**ViewModel**

```
public class FavouriteThingViewModel
{
    public int FavouriteThingID { get; set; }
    public string FavouriteThingName { get; set; }
}
```

**Editor Template**

```
@model _5fave.Models.FavouriteThingViewModel

<div class="control-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FavouriteThingID, new { @class = "control-label" })
    <div class="controls">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FavouriteThingName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FavouriteThingName, null, new { @class = "help-inline" })
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
var favouriteThings = new List<FavouriteThingViewModel>();
    favouriteThings.Add(new FavouriteThingViewModel { FavouriteThingID = 1, FavouriteThingName = "Raindrops on roses" });
    favouriteThings.Add(new FavouriteThingViewModel { FavouriteThingID = 2, FavouriteThingName = "Whiskers on kittens" });
    favouriteThings.Add(new FavouriteThingViewModel { FavouriteThingID = 3, FavouriteThingName = "Bright copper kettles" });
    favouriteThings.Add(new FavouriteThingViewModel { FavouriteThingID = 4, FavouriteThingName = "Warm woolen mittens" });
    favouriteThings.Add(new FavouriteThingViewModel { FavouriteThingID = 5, FavouriteThingName = "Brown paper packages" });

    viewModel.FavouriteThings = favouriteThings;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.FavouriteThingName, Model.FavouriteThingID);
```

As the label is for the textbox for property `FavouriteThingName`.

### Update

From comments below.

If your property is an `int` convert to `string`.

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.FavouriteThingName, Model.FavouriteThingID.ToString());
```

Comment: That looks like it should work but it doesn't. LabelFor seems to renders the literal "FavouriteThingName"

Comment: The label should display the value of `FavouriteThingID` and in the `for` should contain something like `FavouriteThingName`.  If you look at the `id` for the textbox it should be the same, which is correct.

Comment: Thanks Colin, this is what is being rendered: <label for="FavouriteThings_0__FavouriteThingName">FavouriteThingName</label> It seems like the second overload is being ignored.

Comment: Try using .ToString()

Comment: Thanks Colin. I figured that out just before I saw your response.

Comment: awsome answer, really help this

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to set the Display attribute for that prperty

```
public class FavouriteThingViewModel
{

  public int FavouriteThingID { get; set; }

  public string FavouriteThingName { get; set; }
}
```

In your cshtml file

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FavouriteThingID)
```

This will display the values of the property. hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Anto but that isn't the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is working:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.FavouriteThingName, Model.FavouriteThingID.ToString());
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.  The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: Fair enough but why is the above not a complete answer?

Comment: That was an automatic comment made when I was reviewing answers etc. I would just recommend editing your question to include this. And plus, it looks like Colin Bacon already said the same thing above. So simply upvote his answer and accept it. This will indicate you found something that works

Comment: I've just upvoted and accepted Colin's answer. But I figured it out before he posted - that's why I added an answer too.

Comment: I didn't look at the time stamps, sorry